# Java & Spring, Persist a user-defined filter

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jhipster

What im looking to do is to be able to provide the ability for api users to save a filter (e.g. /endpoint?id.in=123,456) for a specific (and eventually, multiple) entity.

To perform the actual filter, i'm using spring data JPA Specifications (with jhipster's Criteria DTO) and that's working like a charm.
However, to persist the actual Specification object or the CriteriaDTO, would be a large (and probably messy) task.

My thought was to create a generic table structure (in postgres) that would support my filtering requirements and be generic enough that it would support all entities. Then use that object to construct the CriteriaDTO and pass that to the entity's service
(if needs be i can post what i had in mind for my table structure)

Before i go down this path, i wanted to get insights from the community, is there a better solution here?

It looks like this is a common enough requirement to have a specific pattern

Answer (score 1):

> However, to persist the actual Specification object or the
>   CriteriaDTO, would be a large (and probably messy) task.

Why would you say that? I am not familiar with how jhipsters `CriteriaDTO` works, but I know how Specifications are created.

In order to create the specification, you need the *search criteria* that you probably get from your API endpoint. It can be a serialized json object, query string parameters, post parameters or whatever.

If you want to save the search criteria for the user, I will suggest storing it in your database as a json (text) field. So, the next time the user wants to filter the data with the same saved filter, just get the stored json, deserialize it and feed it to Specification (no need to serialize the `Specification` object, just the parameters that are used for his creation).

I believe that your way of implementation is also possible but it is harder to implement and I don't see any benefits, except that you might be able to query the filter parameters (for example: find which is the most used filter).

Comment: Thanks for providing an opinion on this. I was torn on the whole situation. Storing it as a json text field makes a lot of sense